# Efficient methods of getting Texas Holdem Poker win probabilities

Tags: python, statistics, simulation, probability, poker

I just found this amazing Texas Holdem Poker odds calculator here:
https://www.888poker.com/poker/poker-odds-calculator

Key features are that it is able to calculate odds with unknown other player cards, variable player numbers and variable play stages.

It's pretty instantaneous so they aren't running a simulation. Other answers on here seem to all point towards using a Monte Carlo simulation, which I would like to avoid.

My question is how do you think they have achieved this? I would like to replicate this to allow me to efficiently calculate approximate win probabilities for large numbers of hands. Any ideas?